Issue with a PHP plugin - Coderflex\Laravisit\Concerns\CanVisit
I have been following a worksheet provided to me by my University teacher. So far I have created a php project around a book club, the next part of my task was for users to be able to comment on a book. I have been told to use this plug-in https://github.com/coderflexx/laravisit/blob/main/src/Concerns/CanVisit.php
I was originally getting an error on my IDE saying

Interface "CoderFlex\Laravisit\Concerns\CanVisit" not found

but once a ran a composer update that issue resolved, however once I loaded up my web page the same error appeared.
I was hoping someone may be more experienced with PHP than I am and would be willing to help
Below is my class:
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Usamamuneerchaudhary\Commentify\Traits\Commentable;
use CoderFlex\Laravisit\Concerns\CanVisit;

class Book extends Model implements CanVisit {

    use Commentable;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table="book_listings";
    protected $fillable=['title', 'author', "publisher_id"];

    public function Publisher() { 
        return $this->belongsTo(Publisher::class); 
    }

    public function visit() {

    }

    public function visits() {

    }
}

And here is my composer.json file
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "coderflexx/laravisit": "^2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.9",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
        "usamamuneerchaudhary/commentify": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.13",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.26",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^8.0",
        "pestphp/pest": "^2.34",
        "pestphp/pest-plugin-laravel": "^2.4"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/coderflexx/laravisit"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi",
            "@php -r \"file_exists('database/database.sqlite') || touch('database/database.sqlite');\"",
            "@php artisan migrate --graceful --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
    
}

So far I have tried verifying the install, I have read through documentation and even tried changing my minimum-stability to be dev in my composer.json file

As per documentation, in your model class you should use HasVisits trait, and implement CanVisit interface . But you have not used the HasVisits traits into your model class. Check the documentation's Usage section again.

Thank you for the response, I have added use HasVisits; to my Book Model class but im still getting Interface "CoderFlex\Laravisit\Concerns\CanVisit" not found
when I load my project

Have you imported this use Coderflex\Laravisit\Concerns\HasVisits; to the top of the Book model class ?Also have you properly installed and published the package?

Yes I have the import at the top of my class,I believe I have the package installed correctly. When i run composer show I can see Coderflexx/laravisit and I have re-run composer require Coderflexx/laravisit to make sure

You have  installed the package but did you  publish the config file by running this command php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Coderflex\Laravisit\LaravisitServiceProvider"? Have you done that?

I originally did not do that so thank you for providing that, but I have run that command and unfortunately still get the same issue.

Which OS you are using i.e. linux or windows ?Which version of laravel you are using ?

Im using macOS 14.5, and Laravel Installer 5.8.2

Current updated laravel version is 11.X why are even using 5.8 ?This is the issue . you need to upgrade the laravel version in order to use this coderflexx/laravisit with version ^2.0. For more info check the link https://packagist.org/packages/coderflexx/laravisit#v2.0.0

Ah sorry I think I checked the wrong version, I have checked the proper one now and I am using laravel 11.19.0. And I am also using version 2.0 for the coderflexx/laravisit

Okay Since you are using macOS try this php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Coderflex\\Laravisit\\LaravisitServiceProvider". And then run php artisan migrate.Because after publishing package a new migration file gets generated.

Unfortunately still no, I can see the migration on my file explorer and in my DB table I can see the table. Put still when I load my project it gives the same error

Hey @Subha weirdly enough I just removed the CanVisit from my declaration of the class and my comments are now working. Im not sure if my Teacher included it by accident but Iooking at the name I thought it would have something to do with page visits, none the less my issue seems to be resolved for now but thank you for your help!

You are welcome, Okay got it,you are not using that CanVisit interface that is why it is working.
